# Pass html table td value to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my html I'm displaying some data from two tables. I provided an edit button for each row of the table. When I click on it, it has to check if the name is existing in table1 or table2 and take all the details of that particular name.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h5 style="text-align: center;">List of SNMP OIDs</h5>
  <table id="myPersonTable" class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
      <%  @all_persons.each do |person|%>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= person['name'] %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>'.html_safe, edit_oid_path(person['id'])%> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= form_tag(contoller: "configuration", action: "delete_person") do%>
              <%= hidden_field_tag(:person_id, person['id'])%>
              <%=submit_tag "Delete", class: "btn btn-danger", data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}%>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Rails Controller:

```
def edit
  person_f =  Person.find_by(name: params[:name])
  person_s= HardPerson.find_by(name: params[:name])
  if person_f.present?
    @person = Oid.find(params[:id])
  elsif person_s.present?
    @oid = HardPerson.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here is a problem: I click on edit button for a person name from person2 
table having id=1. This id exists in person1 and person2 tables both. Instead of taking details from person2 it is checking that id in person1 table and it is getting values for id=1 person details from person1 table

Here in controller `params[:name]` is getting null value. Help me to get `params[:name]` in my rails controller

Answer (score 0):

To get `params[:name]` in your controller use the `:param` option in your routes to override the default resource identifier `:id`

```
resources :people, param: :name
```

This will allow you to use:

```
Person.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

Keep in mind that you might need to to override `ActiveRecord::Base#to_param` of a related model to construct a URL.

See [4.10 Overriding Named Route Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what is your issue, but I'll try. Am I right that you want to see value from `<%= person['name'] %>` as a `params[:name]` inside edit action? Just pass it as additional argument to path helper:

```
<%= link_to '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>'.html_safe, 
  edit_oid_path(person['id'], name: person['name'])%>
```